# INI File wont keep values after exit - RAD Studio 10.4.2

Tags: android, delphi

This simple code was working for a long time. But now it has stopped working.

After app start it loads last position in `Combobox` `last_city`. If I change index of `Combobox`, `last_city` is changed. If I read values all is OK until I exit app. But after I exit app and run app again values are gone.

Any idea why this stopped working? Some changes from google? Api 28 (Android 9). RAD Studio 10.4.2

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var data: string;
  begin
    app_ini := TIniFile.Create(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'app.ini', TEncoding.ANSI);
    data := app_ini.ReadString('nastaveni', 'last_city', '');
    if data <> '' then // load last city
      begin
        cb_mesta.SetFocus;
        cb_mesta.ItemIndex := StrToInt(data);
        cb_mesta.OnChange(Self);
        cb_mezi.ItemIndex := StrToInt(app_ini.ReadString('nastaveni', 'last_adr', ''));
        cb_mezi.OnChange(Self);
        ch_last.IsChecked := True;
      end;
  end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.ch_lastChange(Sender: TObject); // when change city i safe change to ini file
begin
  if ch_last.IsChecked then
    begin
      app_ini.WriteString('nastaveni', 'last_city', IntToStr(cb_mesta.ItemIndex));
      app_ini.WriteString('nastaveni', 'last_adr', IntToStr(cb_mezi.ItemIndex));
    end
  else
    begin
      app_ini.WriteString('nastaveni', 'last_city', '');
      app_ini.WriteString('nastaveni', 'last_adr', '');
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Just to nitpick: why are you reading/writing the values as `string`s when they are clearing `integer`s? `TIniFile` has `ReadInteger()`/`WriteInteger()` methods. In any case, do you have the same problem if you call `TIniFile.UpdateFile()` after writing new values, or at least before exiting the app? You might also consider using `TMemIniFile` instead of `TIniFile`.

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using? If you are using Delphi 10.4 I hope you added `app_ini.Free` into your Form1 `OnDestroy` event.  You see Delphi 10.4 no longer has Automatic Reference Counting meaning that you as a developer are responsible for destroying any classed object that you have created during runtime. Failing to do so on TIniFile class could lead to scenario where not all data gets written into the INI file before your application is closed since TIniFile destructor which makes sure that all data has been written into the INI file before class is destroyed never gets called.

Comment: *This simple code was working for a long time. But now it has stopped working.* So, what exactly did you change in between? Or what has changed in your dev. environment?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, From [System.IniFiles.TIniFile](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IniFiles.TIniFile) : `On non-Windows platforms, TIniFile is a subclass of TMemIniFile that has the AutoSave property always set to True`. This probably means that the `TIniFile` destructor is never called. If the Delphi version is the new non-ARC version, that could the cause.

Comment: @BOB, please update the question with your Delphi version. As said in comments, if you are using a new non-ARC version and not explicitly calling `Free` on `app_ini`, this could be the reason for not storing the updates.

Comment: @Tom Brunberg, i changed version of Delphi from 10.3.3 to 10.4.2

Comment: Ok Bob, then the comments by @SilverWarrior and LURD apply to your case.

Comment: @LU RD, yeah it was it. Thank you for comment.

Comment: @SilverWarior, you right i did NOT add "app_ini.Free" :-( now its working again. Thank you for answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, ehm i really dont know :-D sometimes i pick harder way. But maybe there is something why i did it i dont remember its long time i made it.

Comment: @SilverWarior now that the Delphi version is known, you should move your comment to a proper answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, app_ini.UpdateFile is working also Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code I don't see you cal `app_ini.Free` anywhere.

Why is this important? When you call `app_ini.Free` the destructor for TIniFile class is executed. Before freeing its memory destructor also makes sure that all changes that were made to TIniFile object are written to the INI File before its destruction.

But why aren't these changes written to INI file immediately while they happen? The answer is performance.

You see INI files are text based files. And when you are adding new text to text-based files or if you are replacing part of existing text with another that has a different length all the text that follows the one need to be shifted. This means that you need to read all the text that follows the point you are changing into memory make the change and then write all that text that you have read into memory back to the file. This creates a lot of additional overhead.

In order to avoid this additional overhead the TIniFile is storing its contents in memory and only writes the changes to file when `TIniFile.UpdateFile` is called.

---

**Why did this worked for you in the past and no longer works now?**

When Delphi XE4 first introduced the support for mobile platforms the memory manager for those platforms was based on ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) mechanism.

In ARC based memory management the memory manager is using Reference count of specific object in order to determine whether it needs to be destroyed or not. Reference count is increased every time you reference to a specific object and decreased every time you clear/remove the reference to specific object. And when reference count reaches zero the object is then destroyed.

So in Delphi versions from Delphi XE4 and up to including Delphi 10.3 on mobile platforms you as a developer didn't need to pay much attention to freeing specific object as this was done automatically by memory manager.

But Delphi 10.4 removed the ARC memory management (still remains for Interfaces and strings) with intention of unifying memory management with Windows platforms that never used ARC based memory management (except for Interfaces and Strings).

And since you recently migrated to Delphi 10.4 the code for storing data into INI file used to work fine as it relied on ARC based memory management but stopped working properly now.

---

**PS:** I strongly recommend you go through your whole code because the absence of ARC memory management might be also affection other parts of your code if it was written with ARC based memory management in mind since that code might now be producing memory leaks as the object tht relied to be destroyed by ARC may no longer be destroyed now.

Comment: i dont know if its working for non windows Applications. But enable Memory Leak detection to find all plaes where your missing the frees. (Or my fav: use FastMM)

Answer (score 1):

Reasson were new Delphi and not right wrote app.

First way (Remy Lebeau): `app_ini.UpdateFile;` after writing new values, or at least before exiting the app

Second way(SilverWarior): `app_ini.Free;` into your Form1 OnDestroy event.

But i think best will be both of them for sure of saved values.

Thank you all for help.